# Allow all attributes for TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce

I am building a javascript (Backbone with Coffeescript) app and in this app I am using TinyMCE.

I am adding a new tag with contenteditable set to true but TinyMCE ignores it. How can I allow this attribute?

This is my code:

```
@App.module "Concerns", (Concerns, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->

  Concerns.FormWysiwyg = 

    onDomRefresh: ->
      tinymce.init
        selector: '.wysiwyg'
        height: 350
        menubar: false
        statusbar: false
        plugins: [
          'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor'
          'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen'
          'insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste code'
        ]
        extended_valid_elements: 'span[class|contenteditable]'
        toolbar: 'bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright | bullist numlist outdent indent | link | editable'
        setup: (editor) ->
          editor.on 'change', ->
            editor.save()
          editor.addButton 'editable',
            text: 'Editable'
            icon: false
            onclick: ->
              ed = tinyMCE.activeEditor
              content = ed.selection.getContent({'format':'html'})
              new_selection_content = '<span class="editable yellow" contenteditable="true">' + content + '</span>'
              ed.execCommand('insertHTML', false, new_selection_content)
```